# Getting ERROR ITMS-90005 using application loader

Tags: ios, cordova, application-loader

I'm currently trying to upload an application to Itunes App store using Itunes Connect and Application Loader via Phonegap.
I'm getting the following two errors.

```
ERROR ITMS-90005: "This bundle is invalid. 
The icon file [path to file]/Icon.png must be in .png format."

ERROR ITMS-90005: "This bundle is invalid. 
The icon file [path to file]/Icon@2x.png must be in .png format."
```

I can assure you that the icon files are indeed in .png format when I send them to phonegap. Anyone have any ideas on why I'm getting this error?
(I'm using Phonegap CLI-5.4.1)